# Where to add android:usescleartexttraffic="true" in manifest

Tags: android

If I add it in `<application>` then it is giving me `C:\Users\adity\Desktop\Parse-Server-Starter-Project\ParseStarterProject\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27: AAPT: error: attribute android:usescleartexttraffic not found.`

Comment: Hope This Question would help you! [Link to the Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it a little typo on your code

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` is case sensitive

here the sample overall:

```
<application
        android:name="com.your.app.package"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

and not

```
<application>
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
</application>
```